Kafka Pyspark Streaming packages
Stack

Zookeeper version: 3.6.3 (Confluent 7.3.2)
Kafka version: 3.3.0 (Confluent 7.3.2)
Kafka Schema Registry: Confluent 7.3.2
Kafka Rest Proxy: Confluent 7.3.2
Kafka Connect: Confluent 7.3.2
ksqlDB Server: Confluent 7.3.2
Zoonavigator: 1.1.1

Pyspark Version
-Pyspark 3.2.2
Java JDK 11
error log
SUCCESS: The process with PID 29848 (child process of PID 16408) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 16408 (child process of PID 19596) has been terminated.
                                       & C:/Proyectos/proyectoProcesamiento/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Proyectos/proyectoProcesamiento/venv/consumer_daule.py
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/spark-3.5.3-bin-hadoop3/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: C:\Users\joseb\.ivy2\cache
The jars for the packages stored in: C:\Users\joseb\.ivy2\jars
org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-13918973-ab65-4557-b663-db91cb4aacde;1.0
        confs: [default]
        found org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.0 in central
        found org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.0 in central
        found org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.1 in central
        found org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 in central
        found org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4 in central
        found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.32 in local-m2-cache
        found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.2 in central
        found org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 in central
        found org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.2 in central
        found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 in local-m2-cache
        found com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 in central
        found org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 495ms :: artifacts dl 231ms
        :: modules in use:
        com.google.code.findbugs#jsr305;3.0.0 from central in [default]
        commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.3 from local-m2-cache in [default]
        org.apache.commons#commons-pool2;2.11.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-api;3.3.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-client-runtime;3.3.2 from central in [default]
        org.apache.kafka#kafka-clients;2.8.1 from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.0 from central in [default]
        org.apache.spark#spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12;3.3.0 from central in [default]
        org.lz4#lz4-java;1.8.0 from central in [default]
        org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.32 from local-m2-cache in [default]
        org.spark-project.spark#unused;1.0.0 from central in [default]
        org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.8.4 from central in [default]
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   12  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   12  |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-13918973-ab65-4557-b663-db91cb4aacde
        confs: [default]
        0 artifacts copied, 12 already retrieved (0kB/87ms)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = 5c638ead-57a6-4ef2-a138-ebc701d6ebc0, runId = f7946d33-9dc1-48ad-975c-b7683fb7cdbf]" Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = d9d55bb2-bda6-40e3-8dfe-4936d9cf840b, runId = ce79a1c7-3742-493d-a039-ffaa538bfca4]" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.kafka010.KafkaConfigUpdater
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 86 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$.kafkaParamsForDriver(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:645)
  File "c:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\consumer_daule.py", line 75, in <module>
    query_avg.awaitTermination()
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$3(TreeNode.scala:466)  File "C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\streaming.py", line 101, in awaitTermination
    return self._jsq.awaitTermination()
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^

  File "C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
        answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1216)
  File "C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1215)pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: org/apache/spark/kafka010/KafkaConfigUpdater
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 5c638ead-57a6-4ef2-a138-ebc701d6ebc0, runId = f7946d33-9dc1-48ad-975c-b7683fb7cdbf]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {}

Current State: INITIALIZING
Thread State: RUNNABLE

      org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:211)
PS C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento> SUCCESS: The process with PID 16232 (child process of PID 4712) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 4712 (child process of PID 23988) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 23988 (child process of PID 30344) has been terminated.

Py-spark processing
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, window, avg, count, stddev, expr
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType, TimestampType

# Crear una Spark Session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaSparkStreaming") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0") \
    .getOrCreate()

# Configuración de Kafka
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"  # Cambiar según configuración
kafka_topic = "daule"  # Nombre del topic de Kafka

# Leer datos desde Kafka
kafka_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", kafka_topic) \
    .load()

# Esquema del JSON esperado
schema = StructType([
    StructField("timestamp", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("consumo", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("ciudad", StringType(), True),
    StructField("id_medidor", StringType(), True),
    StructField("region", StringType(), True),
    StructField("latitud", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("longitud", DoubleType(), True)
])

# Parsear JSON desde el campo "value"
parsed_df = kafka_df.select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("data")).select("data.*")

# Calcular el promedio de consumo por región en ventanas de 1 minuto
windowed_avg_df = parsed_df \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "1 minute") \
    .groupBy(
        window(col("timestamp"), "1 minute"),
        col("region")
    ) \
    .agg(
        avg("consumo").alias("promedio_consumo"),
        count("consumo").alias("conteo"),
        stddev("consumo").alias("desviacion_estandar")
    )

# Detectar picos de consumo como valores que superan 3 desviaciones estándar
picos_df = windowed_avg_df \
    .withColumn("limite_superior", col("promedio_consumo") + (3 * col("desviacion_estandar"))) \
    .withColumn("limite_inferior", col("promedio_consumo") - (3 * col("desviacion_estandar"))) \
    .join(parsed_df, ["region"]) \
    .where((col("consumo") > col("limite_superior")) | (col("consumo") < col("limite_inferior"))) \
    .select("timestamp", "region", "ciudad", "consumo", "id_medidor")

# Guardar resultados en HDFS en formato JSON
query_avg = windowed_avg_df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("json") \
    .option("path", r"C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\output") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", r"C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\checkpoint") \
    .start()

query_picos = picos_df \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("json") \
    .option("path", r"C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\output\outliers") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", r"C:\Proyectos\proyectoProcesamiento\venv\checkpoint\outliers") \
    .start()

# Mantener el streaming en ejecución
query_avg.awaitTermination()
query_picos.awaitTermination()


I have tried changing my pyspark installation also tried to do
on bash pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.2.2

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
